# What will happen if an interface extends many other interfaces that have the same default method?

Tags: java, java-8

```
precondition:
1.inteface A extended B,C,D;
2.A,B,C,D have same default method : default Object getById(Long Id){...};

user case:
1.class E implements A;
2.class E call default method getById, then which one will be called?
```

I am confused. It's out of my memory.^_^

Comment: you can just try and see :)

Comment: You would get a compilation error. Try it out.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer when it answers your question.

Comment: Also refer to [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions.

Comment: correct override or compile error,that's what expected,thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordinarily, you'd get an error about duplicate default methods in interfaces.

In this particular case, though, the default method in the subinterface `A.getByID()` would be called, because the subinterface `A` overrides the default methods in its superinterfaces.

If you override a default method in a class/interface, that will take precedence over the default methods in its superinterfaces.

The general case is covered by the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4). (Basically, this boils down to: ambiguity is a compile error, but abstract methods in classes take precedence, and eliminate the ambiguity.)

> **8.4.8.4. Inheriting Methods with Override-Equivalent Signatures**
>
> It is possible for a class to inherit multiple methods with
> override-equivalent signatures (§8.4.2).
>
> It is a compile-time error if a class C inherits a concrete method
> whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited
> by C.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a class C inherits a default method
> whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited
> by C, unless there exists an abstract method declared in a superclass
> of C and inherited by C that is override-equivalent with the two
> methods.

Answer (score 2):

The default method present in the interface A would be called because it overrides the behaviours of its super interfaces.